# Using HttpApplicationState outside ASP.NET session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following problem. I am trying to use web services wrote in ASP.NET in application as intermediate layer, stored inside WCF service layer. So I am instancing some WebService classes and I call web methods like normal C# methods. 
Unfortunately some of them are using asp.net specific solutions like using HttpContext and Application object(of type **HttpApplicationState**). I am trying to add items to this collection before webservice call, but nothing happens! Items are not there after using **Add method**. No exception, nothing. I thought that there is some functionality inside implemenatation of HttpApplicationState class, that prevents this operation in certain cases, but I insepcted code in reflector and everything should be fine... 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Not positive I understand your application structure, but it sounds like you want to run wcf with asp.net compatibility turned on to allow HttpContext?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

Comment: This is half-solution because what I really want to do is to separate aspnet services from any technology and use them as normal classess with business logic.